# Upgrade pip for Python 3.7 on Windows but encounter permission error

Tags: python, permissions, installation, pip, environment

I'm running Win10 64bit and try to install Python3.7 and upgrade pip.

I install my Python at D:\python\python372-64 (and have other versions of python within the python folder).

Pip should come with Python 3. When I run `pip install pip --upgrade`, it says `Found existing installation: pip 18.1` but `Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'd:\\python\\python372-64\\scripts\\pip.exe'. Consider using the '--user' option or check the permissions.'`

So I try to run as an administrator, but it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\python\python372-64\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", mod_spec)
File "d:\python\python372-64\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\Python\Python372-64\Scripts\pip.exe\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pip'
```

However, if I run `python -m ensurepip` I get this:

```
Looking in links: C:\Users\jd\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpcww44m60
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in d:\python\python372-64\lib\site-packages (40.6.2)
Collecting pip
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-18.1
```

Also, here are my environment variables for PATH:

```
D:\Python\Python372-64
D:\Python\Python372-64\Lib\site-packages\
D:\Python\Python372-64\Scripts
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: @Jeremiah I did run as an administrator. please refer to the second part of my question. That's the result I get when I run the command as an administrator.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw that and hoped to delete my comment before you saw it lol.  It could be an environment variables thing.  Is your library directory in your path?

Comment: @Jeremiah I think so: I just add my PATH to the question.

Comment: Hmmm...do you have anaconda prompt by any chance?  I've found that it tends to be a lot less twitchy than the vanilla cmd for working with pip.  I also found a mention of this slightly more verbose install command for upgrading pip on windows using the regular command prompt `python -m pip install --upgrade pip`.  Apparently there is an issue on windows with exe files being unable to be modified while open.  This should work if that's what is causing the failure.

Comment: @Jeremiah No I don't have anaconda installed. I think I just figured it out! Writing up the answer now, but I hope there is no further issues later...Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved it!

`py -3.72 -m pip install --upgrade pip`